# export GeoPDF when using tmap_save

Tags: r, geospatial, spatial, tmap

When saving a plot as pdf with tmap the result file does not keep the Spatial information of the shapes or rasters used, is there a way to include it?.

Command used:

```
tmap_save(m_map,"result_map.pdf")
```

Comment: Interesting question. But I think `tmap_save()` is not designed to pass spatial information to its output file. Consider suggesting this [here](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues).

Answer (score 0):

**tmap_save()** function is for saving your maps as an image (for example in a png format or pdf format). If you want to *store* an spatial object you should use functions as **st_write()** . Or if you want to add information to your map you can manipulate the legend or add some text.